# What is the equivalent of Cisco's 'ip virtual-reassembly' for a Juniper ISG 2000

Tags: cisco, udp, juniper, fragmentation

I tested my dns servers with the [oarc test](https://www.dns-oarc.net/oarc/services/replysizetest) and my size limit is at least 1403 bytes. I performed the same test before my Juniper ISG 2000 and the result is 2047 bytes.

According to the chapter IP ["Fragments Filtered"](https://www.dns-oarc.net/oarc/services/replysizetest) and this [article](http://www.bortzmeyer.org/dns-size.html), I think I have a fragmentation problem.

This [article](http://www.bortzmeyer.org/dns-size.html) talks about `ip virtual-reassembly` for cisco but I can't find the equivalent for Juniper.

I prefer to find the good option in JunOS before I talk about this with my net admin :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The ISG-2000 is actually a stateful firewall with several other features and options (VPN, IPS, etc.).  It runs not JunOS but ScreenOS, as it's a NetScreen firewall.

Assuming you're running ScreenOS 6.2.0 or newer, you should be able to enable IP packet reassembly as follows:

```
set flow force-ip-reassembly
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, there is no option on things other than GRE tunnels, and possibly all tunnels.

Is there any chance of using a stateful firewall, as I believe that may also enable reassembly?

Comment: Yes, it seems a stateful firewall is the only solution if you insist on having a firewall: http://www-jnet.juniper.net/techpubs/software/erx/junose80/swconfig-ip-services/download/firewall-config.pdf "To ward against attacks that use fragmentation, the JUNOS
stateful firewall supports virtual reassembly for TCP and UDP packets,..."